# Azure Custom Script Extensions with a Windows VM and azure-cli: Publisher is Invalid

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, cloud, azure-cli

I'm trying to provision some VMs on Azure and immediately after customize them with a script. It seems the best way to accomplish this is with Custom Script Extensions.

When I try and execute `az extension set` on a VM that I have created, it bombs and complains that

> The value of parameter publisher is invalid.

This is presumably because I have set myself as the publisher. Instead of `Microsoft.OSTCExtensions` or some other commonly accepted Extension publisher.

The name `Custom Script Extension` implies to me that *CUSTOM* scripts can be chainloaded via this method. Is that not possible without first becoming an extension *publisher*?

The commands I'm executing:

**Set an Extension:**

```
az vm extension set --resource-group dev-eu2 --vm-name dev-eu2-dc --name deploy_ad_to_eu2.ps1 --publisher "zimmertr" --settings /home/tj/git/Dev.Builder/azure-cli/script_extensions/domain_controller/dc_eu2.json --version v0.1
```

**The JSON being called by said extension:**

```
{
  "fileUris": ["http://localhost:8000/powershell/domain_controllers/deploy_ad_to_eu2.ps1"],
  "commandToExecute": "./deploy_ad_to_eu2.ps1"
}
```

This JSON then calls `deploy_ad_to_eu2.ps1`, which is a Powershell script running on a fileserver on my computer. I know this PowerShell script is 100% working because I can copypaste it into a PowerShell prompt without any issues. I'm just tired of RDPing into servers and looking for a little automation.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Johan said, we should use `Microsoft.compute` as the publisher and use `CustomscriptExtension` as the name of the extension.

By the way, we should use `--version` to **1.9**, the json should like this:

```
{
  "fileUris": ["https://jasonvmdiag956.blob.core.windows.net/jasonvmtest/jason.ps1"],
  "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe ./jason.ps1"
}
```

We can run this script in Azure CLI 2.0 like this:

```
az vm extension set --resource-group jasonvm --vm-name jasonvm --name CustomScriptExtension --publisher Microsoft.Compute --settings D:\cert\qq.json --version 1.9
```

The output like this:

```
C:\Users>az vm extension set --resource-group jasonvm --vm-name jasonvm --name CustomScriptExtension --publisher Microsoft.Compute --settings D:\cert\qq.json --version 1.9
{| Finished ..
  "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
  "forceUpdateTag": null,
  "id": "/subscriptions/5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe29axxxx/resourceGroups/jasonvm/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/jasonvm/extensions/CustomScriptExtension",
  "instanceView": null,
  "location": "eastus",
  "name": "CustomScriptExtension",
  "protectedSettings": null,
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
  "resourceGroup": "jasonvm",
  "settings": {
    "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe ./jason.ps1",
    "fileUris": [
      "https://jasonvmdiag956.blob.core.windows.net/jasonvmtest/jason.ps1"
    ]
  },
  "tags": null,
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "typeHandlerVersion": "1.9",
  "virtualMachineExtensionType": "CustomScriptExtension"
}
```

---

**Update:**

I had test this PowerShell in my lab, it works fine, here are my steps:
1.**upload** that powershell script to Azure storage account container(type:container):

[image]
2.**create json file** in your local PC:

```
{
  "fileUris": ["https://jasonvmsdiag665.blob.core.windows.net/ps1/installad.ps1"],
  "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe ./installad.ps1"
}
```

[image]
3.**run** that script in CLI 2.0:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157945/discussion-on-answer-by-jason-ye-msft-azure-custom-script-extensions-with-a-wi).

Answer (score 1):

The publisher refers to the publisher of the extension itself, not the publisher of the script to execute. The combination of publisher and name uniquely identifies *which* extension to apply to the Virtual Machine.

The `Microsoft.Compute CustomScriptExtension` extension (where `Microsoft.Compute` is the publisher and `CustomScriptExtension` is the name of the extension) is general purpose in that the script for the extension to execute is fed through the configuration. Thus there is no need to publish one extension per script.

In other words, you should not specify yourself as the publisher, you should specify the actual publisher of the extension and use the configuration to specify which script(s) you want to execute.

Comment: Thank you Johan! I think the real root of my issue was not passing `powershell.exe` as part of the `commandToExecute` field.

Comment: Please see my reply to Jason, Johan. It offers insight into a further issue that I am now experiencing.